# Why shortcut link on my Ubuntu doesn't work after I restart or shutdown my system?

Tags: shortcuts

Every time I create a new shortcut link and restart/shutdown my PC, it says link is broken and move to trash?

I have created multiple shortcut link from different sources to different locations on Ubuntu but result is same.
[image: error says-Link broken]

I tried to turn it OFF and ON, as in below image:-
[image]

Comment: Are you sure `New Volume1` is being mounted at startup?

Comment: Do you have your mount points set to use UUIDs or are they automatic?  There is a chance that when you reboot your host that your drive designations are changing during reboot.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I went to "disks" and can see that "automatic mount option" is ON and checked by default. I tried turning it OFF and confirmed that Mount at Startup is checked but it didn't work out.      Is there any command I need to run?